# Need to acces localhost from my android device

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a php file in the following folder:

```
C:\wamp\www\android_test\fetch_data2
```

I need to be able to access this file from my application but am unable to get access to it as of now. Here is my Java code and I will highlight where I need to fix. I can access the php file from my computer through localhost/android_data......, but I cannot access it from my phone browser. Also I have no code written in the accompanying xml file and maybe that is why my php file does not show up on the application.

Addition notes: I just want my app to display this php file which is connected to a mysql data base and outputs:

```
 [{"name":"User1","received_power":"-75.12207037710479","tower":"4","status":"0"},{"name":"User2","received_power":"18.89454151068304","tower":"3","status":"0"}]
```

My java file called MySQLData.java has the following inside:

```
package com.example.qosmetre2;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.List; 

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair; 
import org.json.JSONArray; 
import org.json.JSONException; 
import org.json.JSONObject; 

import android.app.ListActivity; 
import android.app.ProgressDialog; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.AsyncTask; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.AdapterView; 
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; 
import android.widget.ListAdapter; 
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MySQLData extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb=null;
        //String result=null;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //http post

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://174.112.97.111/android_test/fetch_data2.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string

        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();

        }catch(Exception e){

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        //paring data

        String nam;
        int rec_pow;
        int tow;
        int stat;

        try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data=null;

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                nam=json_data.getString("name");
                rec_pow=json_data.getInt("recieved_power");
                tow=json_data.getInt("tower");
                stat=json_data.getInt("status");

        }

        }catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Could not Parse Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (ParseException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

There is also another file called MainActivity.java that has nothing inside except the default stuff, and there is an xml file called main_activity.xml that has nothing inside it.

here is my andoidmanifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.qosmetre2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.qosmetre2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".MySQLData"
        android:label="All the Data" > 
    </activity> 

</application>
```

Comment: Are both devices on the same network?

Comment: I am assuming that http://174.112.97.111 is a site that your Android device can access... did you try to do so from a browser on the Android? I couldn't get to it from my computer. As @RaghavSood hinted at - if the Android can't see the server all bets are off.

Comment: The cause for this problem is probably that your wamp is configured to not accept any connections not coming from localhost.

Answer (score 2):

If both devices are on the same network, AND you'll only be using this app when you are at home/connected to the same network, then you can use the local IP address assigned to your computer by your router, probably something like `192.168.1.4`

If you're going to want to use this app on 3G/4G or another WiFi connection away from your computer, you'll need to edit your routers port forwarding settings and then you'll connect to it using your router's IP address. You can also register a free domain name that is connected to that IP address so you won't have to remember a bunch of numbers.

This is not a coding issue though...

Comment: i want to use the app not at home so not from the same network. My Ipv$ address is 192.168.0.10 ive been trying to port forward this app, but im having issues with that as well. The parameters i have to fill out are: Name   
Type  TCP UDP TCP/UDP  
LAN Server IP ... 
Remote IPs  Any Single address Address Range  
Start IP ...   
End IP ... 

Public IP Ports  Port Range Single Port  

Start Public Port   
End Public Port   
Private Ports

Comment: and as far as the xml what should i do with that? should i leave it and something will show up?

Comment: the xml file is your layout... as for the port forwarding, it will be port 80 (http port) and the LAN Server IP will be the IP of your computer

Comment: yeah but will the infromation that the php file is getting from the mysql database show up in the application? (or do i need to edit the xml file and how would i do that considering my code)

Comment: You're already setting your layout right here: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` I'm not sure I understand what you're asking...

Comment: You've extended a ListActivity, but I don't see anywhere in your code where you are adding anything at all to a ListView. These are two separate questions. Consider asking another specific to your layout issues and adding items to your ListView

Comment: im basically geting a table from mysql and accessing it from my php script. Now i want that to show ip in my android application. The only purpose of my android application is to show the mysql database. Now what im asking is, is my activity_main going to recieve the data from MySQLData.java automatically, or do i have to write some code in the activity_main.xml file

Comment: an xml file is ONLY a layout file in Android. You should at the very least have a ListView because you're inflating that layout inside of a ListActivity.

Comment: okay thanks, and for the port forwarding, i go to cmd prompt and type ipconfig and it gives me many different ip addresses. when i go to the smc port worwarding area on the browser the LAN server IP automatically starts wit 192.168.____._____. which one of the ips am i supposed to use.

Comment: probably the .0.10 one I think is what you said. You can test it though by replacing `localhost` with `192.168.0.10` in your broswer

Comment: it says "illegal port number" when i put 80. then it says "public port conflict with remote management ports" BTW thatnks for all the help so far

Comment: You should probably turn off Remote Management. Either that or you'll need to configure WAMP to listen on a different port, such as 8080, however; then your url will need to look like `192.168.0.10/mypage.php:8080`

Comment: how would i turn off remote management

Comment: Check through the settings of your router. If you can't find it search Google, I'm sure you'll find someone with the same router that's wanted to do the same thing